# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT] : Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client in updating profile API in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

I'm fairly new to Node.js and I am having some issues.

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)
at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:644:11)
at ServerResponse.header (F:\projects\Node_js\Node_js\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:794:10)

```
exports.update_profile = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let rules =
    {
      username: req.body.username,
      email: req.body.email,
      mobile: req.body.mobile,
      companyname: req.body.companyname,
    };

    if (req.files && req.files.Profile_images) {
      req.body['Profile_images'] = req.files.Profile_images;
    }

    const user = new User(req.body, rules);
    user.save(err => {
          if (err) {
            res.status(500).send({ message: err });
            return;
          }
        });

    let current_user = req.User;

    if (req.files && req.files.Profile_images) {
      var image_file = req.files.Profile_images;
      var image_file_name = Date.now() + '-Profile-images-' + image_file_name;
      var image_path = publicPath + '/Profile_images/' + image_file_name;
      await image_file.mv(image_path);
      if (current_user.profile_image && current_user.profile_image == '') {
        let old_path = publicPath + '/Profile_images/' + current_user.Profile_images;
        if (fs.existsSync(old_path)) {
          fs.unlinkSync(old_path);
        }
      }
    } else {
      var image_file_name = current_user.Profile_images;
    }

    await User.updateOne({
      _id: current_user._id
    }, {
      username: req.body.username,
      email: req.body.email,
      mobile: req.body.mobile,
      companyname: req.body.companyname,
      profile_image: image_file_name,
      profession: req.body.profession ? req.body.profession : ''
    });

    let userData = await User.findOne({ _id: current_user._id })
    let jwt_secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET || 'mysecret';
    let token = jwt.sign({
      data: userData
    }, jwt_secret, { expiresIn: '12h' });

    return res.status(200).send({ message: 'Profile Updated Successfully Updated', data: userData, token: token });

  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(404).send({ message: error.message });
  }
}
```

This is my code of Update Profile
May I know what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Which line causes the error in the code you posted?

Comment: I don't know that

Comment: either line 393 or 794 as indicated by your error text (i don't remember the order of the stack in node). But we only have a part of the code so we don't have the actual lines. If those lines don't fit you can add a `try ... catch` to your function to have the line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error handler in `user.save()` throw an error -> a 500 response has been sent to client but the code continue -> ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT. Please change your code:

From:

```
user.save(err => {
          if (err) {
            res.status(500).send({ message: err });
            return;
          }
        });
```

To: `await user.save()`

Then it will log something more useful.

Comment: That was my intuition too, the OP probably meant the `return` as an exit from `update_profile` whereas it just exists the "user.save" callback. I thought so because the `return` here is useless as written